# A diagram in xymatrix, and a problem with arrows

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

In the code below, the arrows from left to right and up and down get mixed up and look like a single arrow. How can I separate them so that I have one arrow> pointing up and one pointing down, and the same for the right/left arrows?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, oneside]{amsart} \usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

Consider the following diagram.
$$ 
\xymatrix{  
A \ar[r]_{f} \ar[d]_{k} &  \ar[l]_{g} \ar[d]^{s}  B \\    
C \ar[u]_{l} \ar[r]_{p}   &  D. \ar[l]_{q} \ar[u]^{t} 
} 
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) don't use `$$...$$`, it is not LaTeX, (2) No blank lines in math mode, (3) I assume `B \ C` is suppose to be `B \\ C` because then it compiles just fine.

Comment: Generally I suggest having `&` and ``\\`` on lines of their own for constructions like this as it makes it easier to see what belongs where.

Comment: It is not a good idea to just edit your example, then your question no longer makes sense to others finding it in the future. Would be better to post additions to the question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to shift the arrows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

Consider the following diagram.
\[
\xymatrix{
A \ar@<-0.5ex>[r]_{f} \ar@<-0.5ex>[d]_{k} &  \ar@<-0.5ex>[l]_{g} \ar@<0.5ex>[d]^{s}  B \\
C \ar@<-0.5ex>[u]_{l} \ar@<-0.5ex>[r]_{p}   &  D\rlap{.} \ar@<-0.5ex>[l]_{q} \ar@<0.5ex>[u]^{t}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note the addition of the `cmtip` option that makes good arrow tips as opposed to the horrible ones you get without it.

[image]

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

Consider the following diagram.
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,shift right=0.5ex,"f"'] \arrow[d,shift right=0.5ex,"k"'] &
B \arrow[l,shift right=0.5ex,"g"'] \arrow[d,shift left=0.5ex,"s"] \\
C \arrow[u,shift right=0.5ex,"l"'] \arrow[r,shift right=0.5ex,"p"'] &
D\rlap{.} \arrow[l,shift right=0.5ex,"q"'] \arrow[u,shift left=0.5ex,"t"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I consider this more natural: right and left are relative to the direction of the arrow. A quote like in `"f"'` means that the label is “below” the arrow (that is, at the right).